# How to add object into array with ES6 ... method ?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I know how to do with push method:

```
import * as types from '../constants/ActionTypes'

const initialState = {
  designBox: [],

}

import * as types from '../constants/ActionTypes'
const initialState = {
  designBox: [],

}

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
  case types.CREATE_DESIGN_BOX:
    let newState = Object.assign({}, state);
    newState.designBox.push(action.payload)
    return newState

  default:
    return state
  }
}
```

But I don't know how to do with `...` method

Now my code has problem, The designBox can't add objects,
it only has one item, because it just overwritten by new `action.payload`

```
import * as types from '../constants/ActionTypes'

const initialState = {
  designBox: [],

}

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
  // action.payload format -> { width:200,height:300,text:'abc'}
  case types.CREATE_BOX:
    return {
      ...state,
      designBox: [action.payload]
    }
  default:
    return state
  }
}
```

How can I do this with ... method  ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spread the the array as well:

```
return {
  ...state,
  designBox: [...state.designBox, action.payload]
}
```

Also, your state doesn't need to be an object. If it only contains an array just make it an array:

```
const initialState = [];
```

Comment: Is it a common way the initialState is array not object??

Comment: If it only has one key which has an array as an value anyway, then there is no reason to nest the stuff you want to access later a level deeper than necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Use array destructor

```
case types.CREATE_BOX:
    return {
      ...state,
      designBox: [...state.designBox,action.payload]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no way using object spread to manipulate keys, only replace them entirely. You can however refer to the original object when you're overriding keys:

```
return {
  ...state,
  designBox: state.designBox.concat(action.payload)
}
```